# Installing Wordpress: "wordpress address" different to "site address"

Tags: wordpress

I am searching some documentation or information about how to install Wordpress in a directory, but access to it with another address. That is, I have my hosting in "mydomain.com". My installation directory will be "blog_md", but I want to access to it using "mydomain.com/blog".

I have tried to do this installing Wordpress in the directory that I said above ("blog_md"), and when the installation is finished, I go to Admin site > Settings > General. Here, I have:

> Wordpress address: mydomain.com/blog_md
>
> Site address: mydomain.com/blog_md

Then, I change site address to say what address will use my readers to access my blog. I will have:

> Wordpress address: mydomain.com/blog_md
>
> Site address: mydomain.com/blog

When I do this, I can surf my admin site, but when I go to mydomain.com/blog, I get an error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /blog/ was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

However, I can see the blog when I access to mydomain.com/blog_md, but all links point to mydomain.com/blog, so when I do click in any link, I get the above error.

Could you help me, please?
Thank you very much.

Israel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this guide from Wordpress, I'm sure it will give you some ideas: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

> Many people want WordPress to power their website's root (e.g.
>   http://example.com) but they don't want all of the WordPress files
>   cluttering up their root directory. WordPress allows you to install it
>   into a subdirectory, but have your website served from the website
>   root.

Comment: There isn´t my case. But I could solved storing files in "blog_md", and creating another directory "blog" where I stored next modified files: .htaccess and index.php